# Optimized way of taking a dataframe and ensuring it has the same indexes of another?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, concatenation

Currently, I have a function that has two inputs, data frame 1 and data frame 2, and makes it so data frame 2 has the same indexes as data frame 1, having interpolated values in the mix. For larger dataframes the code is computational expensive (a result of the concatenate), and I was wondering if there were any better ways to achieve the same result.

The index of the dataframe I am currently using is based on time. Here is my current code:

```
import pandas as pd

def data_frame_fill_by_index(data_frame_1, data_frame_2):
    # Find what times are missing from the dataframe
    missing_index = data_frame_1.index.difference(data_frame_2.index)
    # Create those indexes/times with nan
    add_times = pd.DataFrame(index=missing_index, columns=data_frame_2.columns)
    # Add the index/time
    data_frame_2 = pd.concat([data_frame_2, add_times], ignore_index=False)
    # Interpolate all the points
    data_frame_2 = data_frame_2.astype('float').interpolate(method='index', limit_direction='both')
    # Get the points that are tested for rest
    data_frame_2 = data_frame_2.loc[data_frame_1.index]
    # Ensure no duplicate times in the dataframe
    data_frame_2 = data_frame_2[~data_frame_2.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
    return data_frame_1, data_frame_2
```

Comment: "most likely a result of..." - instead of guessing, use `line_profiler` to check where is your bottleneck

Comment: Thanks! I've corrected it - it is a result of the concat(), which is known to be slow for large dataframes. However, I do not know an alternative in this case.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe concatenate values (numpy arrays), sort if necessary, and make DataFrame out of the resulting concatenated numpy array. Also, I strongly suggest to create [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - its best way to make more people willing to help you (its much easier to help and also more fun).